# MySQL is insanely slow on fresh installed Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: mysql

Yesterday I installed Ubuntu 17.10 on my desktop and today I wanted to migrate a MySQL datababase (`php artisan migrate:fresh` with laravel), but my database was very slow. The migrations only, took around 30 seconds.

On my macbook these migrations take only a few seconds (under 5 seconds).

I tried google and got a lot of settings I could change in `my.cnf`.
For example the following settings:

```
[mysqld]
innodb_io_capacity = 2000
innodb_read_io_threads = 64
innodb_thread_concurrency = 0
innodb_write_io_threads = 64
```

This didn't made it any faster. I also found the option for slow query logging, but the output file is empty after the migrations.

Does someone have any other solutions?

Ps. I removed the settings from `my.cnf` because it didn't made it faster and I wasn't sure whether to keep the settings or not.

I have mysql-server-5.7.

Comment: Didnt you ask EXACTLY this a couple of hours ago

Comment: Do a select * from table limit 10000; then see how much time it'll take. Also consider indexes.

Answer (score 1):

`long_query_time = 1` (or possibly a lower value); this will help get something useful in the slowlog.

With rare exceptions, "You can't tune you way out of a performance problem."

How much RAM?

Find some slow SQL so we can discuss it.  Please provide the corresponding `SHOW CREATE TABLE` so we know what the table(s) look like.

Answer (score -1):

```
# Set innodb_buffer_pool_size to 70-80 % of RAM
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 4G
# Set .._log_file_size to 25 % of buffer pool size
innodb_log_file_size = 1G
```

Comment: Why these numbers? Do we know how much RAM the server has?

Comment: The comments are good; the values in the actual assignments are examples.